# Fragement class inside a recycler view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

i know that i can use a recycler view to show a list of item but what if I wanna show a list of existing Fragments?
I'll try to explain better with an example:

In my app I have a fragment called review that's look like this:

```
public class ReviewView extends Fragment implements ReviewViewContract.View {
    private TextView tvContent, tvName,tvDate,tvReactionCounter, tvCommentCountCounter;
    private ImageView userPhoto;
    private ImageButton btnMore;
    private Button btnComment, btnLike;
    private PopupMenu popup;
    private ReviewViewContract.Presenter presenter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_review, container, false);
        presenter = new ReviewViewPresenter(this,getContext(),getArguments());
        initComponent(v);
        presenter.getDetail();
        return v;
    }
    //Some view methods...
    @Override
    public void initComponent(View view) {
        userPhoto = view.findViewById(R.id.img_userphoto_profile);
        tvName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name_profile);
        tvDate = view.findViewById(R.id.tvdate_profile);
        tvContent =  view.findViewById(R.id.content_review_component);
        tvReactionCounter = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_reactionCounter);
        tvCommentCountCounter = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_commentsCounter);
        btnComment = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_comment);
        btnLike=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_like);
        popup= new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), btnMore);
        popup.getMenuInflater()
                .inflate(R.menu.menu_review, popup.getMenu());
        btnMore = view.findViewById(R.id.more_review);
        popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), btnMore);
        popup.getMenuInflater()
                .inflate(R.menu.menu_review, popup.getMenu());
        btnMore.setOnClickListener(v->popup.show());
    }
    @Override
    public void setDetail(String title, String date, String authorImageURL, String overView) {
        tvName.setText("ciao");
    }
    private void likeBtnListener(){...};
    private void commentsBtnListener(){...};
}
```

Now I need to show an indefinite number of reviewView in my activity, I thought to use a recycler view to do that but I do not want to rewrite all methods of ReviewView in the viewHolder class,(it doesn't seem a smart thing to do)  so what should I do?

PS: I know that I can archive this with something like

```
Review fragment = new ReviewView();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment); 
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But this way doesn't seem the best way to do this.

Comment: So you want to add Fragments in RecyclerView? That's not possible. You will have to rethink your whole implementation.

Comment: So the only way it's use the FragmentManager way?

Comment: It depends even on your design. You can create an Adapter with Fragment and use to show them using ViewPager for example, but that depends on your design and the way you want to present that information to the user.